# How to show button based on the status id in axios get?

Tags: javascript

I want to display button based on status id. If status id is `2` the `ADD` will be showed up to the user.
I'm using axios get function.

below is my code

```
 $("#detailsContent").html(response.data.result.map((a) => { 

      let statusData= '';

         if(a.status.id === '2'){
             statusData+=`<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="add()">ADD</button>`;
         }

     return`
     <div class="nk-block">
                            <div class="info">
                                <ul class="meta">
                                    <li class="id"><span> Type:</span> <strong>${a.status.type}</strong></li>
                                    <li class="date"><span>Submitted:</span> <strong>${a.status.date}</strong></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary">${a.status.name}</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="status">
                                    ${statusData}
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
`;
}
```

if the `status.id == 2`
I want it to show the button `ADD` add the highlighted area
[button area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j99zF.png)

With the my current code its not working even if the status id is `2` the button `ADD` still now showed up. How do I fix my code in order to display the button ?

Comment: Maybe a.status.id is 2 not '2' so change it like this  if(a.status.id === 2)

Comment: yes, i just realize this. silly mistake thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make silly mistake for this it should be like this `if(a.status.id === 2)`
and not like this  `if(a.status.id === '2')`